# Why I failed to install mongo under my kubuntu 20?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I tried to install mongo under my kubuntu 20, but I got errors:

```
root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads# wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
OK
root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads# sudo apt-get install gnupg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-database : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd64-microcode appmenu-gtk-module-common intel-microcode iucode-tool libappmenu-gtk3-parser0 libboost-program-options1.71.0 libfwupdplugin1 libgoogle-perftools4 libllvm11 libpcrecpp0v5 libreoffice-help-common libtcmalloc-minimal4
  libxmlb1 libyaml-cpp0.6 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 mongo-tools mongodb-server-core thermald
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/97.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 242 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 289765 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_6.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (6.0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_6.0.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_6.0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (6.0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_6.0.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-database-tools_100.6.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.6.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.6.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_6.0.3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_6.0.3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.6.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads#  uname -a
Linux master-at-home 5.15.0-53-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 15:10:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads# 
root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads# lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
5.15.0-53-generic
x86_64
```

How that can be fixed ?

Comment: You didn't uninstall mongodb 3.6 before installation of 6.0. Uninstall old version first, then install new.